# SWT: Is it possible to add send to back" behavior for a Shell that is always on top?

Tags: java, shell, swt

I have an SWT Application that has a window that is always on top. I would like other windows of the application to be able to be on top of this window, without necessarily being always on top themselves. I.e. I want to send this window to the back.

The window was created with a new Shell with the `SWT.ON_TOP` style flag.

```
Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.BORDER | SWT.ON_TOP);
```

Is it possible to change that style programmatically?

Or is there a different way to send a shell to the back?

Comment: Well "always on top" is quite clear. There is nothing that can be on top of it... You can't change the style on the fly either. What you could do, is either make the `Shell` invisible or minimize it.